# How to fit a div exactly onto an underlaying image - the div is always slightly bigger in height

Tags: html, css

I've built a simple example pen: http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/tcwFj. I have a large image going completely across the whole container width. My goal was to get a div containing a headline and text to overlay one half of the image (in the example I've covered it completely).

Problem is I've assigned an height of `100%` to the overlay div which refers to the parent article element - now the overlay is slightly higher than the image.
Guess it is due to the context.

Is there an elegant way to solve and work around that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following works:

```
img {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto; //!important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

`img` is inline and has a small space below it due to line leading.

Adding `vertical-align: top` fixes it.

See demo at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rfCuz

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think i know what's on my to do list tomorrow morning - trying to understand why the vertical-align worked. ;) Elegant solution, i already feared more trouble. Thanks again!